# using NSNumberFormatter with NSDecimalNumberHandler in the iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, numbers, nsnumber

as a quick test of formatting very large, precise numbers i'm doing:

```
(number is a synthesized NSDecimalNumber...)
number = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDecimal:[[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:420000008698643507200000.0F] decimalValue]];
DLog(@"unformatted: %@", [number stringValue]);
```

which gives me: "unformatted: 420000008698643507200000"

but when i try to format it via `NSNumberFormatter`, it's quite off... rounding way up or something...

```
  numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
  [numFormatter setNumberStyle:kCFNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
  [numFormatter setRoundingMode:kCFNumberFormatterRoundDown];
  [numFormatter setMaximum:nil];

  DLog(@"formatted: %@", [numFormatter stringFromNumber:number]);
```

gives me: "formatted: 420,000,008,698,644,000,000,000"

i'm hoping there's some secret `NSNumberFormatter` magic property that i'm not seeing, but I tried `setUsesSignificantDigits` and `setMaximumSignificantDigits`, but that didn't seem to work.

anyone have any ideas? thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loss of precision comes from the fact that `NSNumberFormatter` converts the number to a double.

Have you considered using `NSDecimalNumber's descriptionWithLocale:` method? As a starting point you could just pass in `[NSLocale currentLocale]` as a param. Then you can start playing with the locale configuration via `NSLocaleDecimalSeparator` and `NSLocaleGroupingSeparator`.